# Customer can not login in frontend with secure url....after ssl configuration

Tags: login, cookie, ssl, secure

I configured SSl in magento. login url and checkout url....
But its login is not working....
My setting are

```
In system web option
Auto-redirect to Base URL----> NO
Use Secure URLs in Frontend-----> yes
Use Secure URLs in Admin  ----->  NO
Use SID on Frontend------------> YES
Cookie Domain---------------> site base url(http://example.com)
Use HTTP Only------------->yes
```

Now Problem is this When I login by frontend its not redirecting....also not login ...

Comment: Check if you are facing any CROS issue

Comment: @Trimantra Software Solution  I m not facing cross issue...after filling login id and pwd ...again it returned me on login page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookie domain must not include the URL scheme. So it is supposed to be `example.com` or, to also match subdomains, `.example.com`.